# Unity Firebase Realtime Database ValueChanged Listener Null Value, Android Build Only

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I first encountered this in my app, but found it is reproducible in minimalist projects as well. I have a public database **(read & write: true)** and in Unity I use the following script to add a listener to a value in my database and to update some text on the screen when that value changes. I have a button in my scene which calls **"ToggleValue()"** to switch between existing and null values.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Database;

public class DataTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text displayText;
    private bool toggleState = false;


    void Start () {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("test").ValueChanged += HandleTestChanged;
    }

    void HandleTestChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
        if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
            displayText.text = args.DatabaseError.Message;
            Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
            return;
        } else {
            displayText.text = args.Snapshot.Value.ToString();
        }

    }

    public void ToggleValue() {
        toggleState = !toggleState;
        Dictionary<string, object> testChanges = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (toggleState) {
            testChanges.Add("test", true);
        } else {
            testChanges.Add("test", null);
        }
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.UpdateChildrenAsync(new Dictionary<string, object>(testChanges));
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine in the editor. When clicking the button the text on screen displays "True" and "null" at the appropriate times. However, when I build to Android, I get different results. The first time the value is set to True, the text updates to read **"True"**. However, on the second press, when the listener should trigger with a value of **"null"**, nothing happens. The **"HandleTestChanged"** function is not called, no new value is passed in. Having the Firebase Realtime Database console window open on my desktop I can see that the value is still being set correctly, it's just not updating the clients.

Is anyone else able to reproduce this? Does anyone have a workaround for this?

**I am using Unity 2018.2.1f1, Firebase Unity SDK 5.2.0, Android 7.1.1.**